# knitr code chunks in footnotes

Tags: knitr, sweave, fancyvrb

My issue is to include verbatim output from knitr Sweave code chunks in footnotes.  The BVerbatim environment (*fancyvrb*) gives me the formatting that I want.  (NB: one needs to put \VerbatimFootnotes somewhere following the preamble.)  With the chunk option `results='asis'` the code is delimited with \begin{Sinput} ... \end{Sinput}. Is there a way to ensure that these do not appear, or to omit them? An example is at the end of the post.

If I include the output directly in the footnote, whether with `results='asis'` or `results='markup'`, the formatting is untidy and the code appears normalsize, even if I have `size='footnotesize'` as a chunk option.  I can of course admit defeat and include the code directly in a BVerbatim environment, with the concurrent risk that the code that is printed is not guaranteed to be the code that is executed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\VerbatimFootnotes
<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@

<<install-pkg, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE>>=
repos <- "http://cran.csiro.au"
install.packages('httr', repos=repos)}
@ 

To install the package {\em httr}, execute
the code in the footnote.\footnote{
\begin{BVerbatim}[baseline=t]
<<install-pkg, eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE, results="asis">>=
@ 
\end{BVerbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is question number 100000, hurray!

Comment: Could you post a minimal example to make it easier for us to get started on diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following is clumsy, but achieves what I want

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \begin{document}
    \VerbatimFootnotes
    \newcommand*\FancyVerbStopString{'zzz'}
    <<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
    render_listings()
    @

    <<install-pkg, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE>>=
    repos <- "http://cran.csiro.au"
    install.packages('httr', repos=repos)}
    @ 

    To install the package {\em httr}, execute
    the code in the footnote.\footnote{
    \begin{BVerbatim}[baseline=t, firstline=2, lastline=3] 
    <<install-pkg-fn, eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE, highlight=FALSE, results="asis">>=
    <<install-pkg>>
    'zzz'
    @ 
    \end{BVerbatim}
    }
    \end{document}
```

The effect of **firstline=2** is to drop off the \begin{Sinput}.  One could specify **lastline=3** to drop off the \end{Sinput}.  However, for automatic use, this requires a mechanism for counting the number of lines of code.  Hence the use of

```
        \newcommand*\FancyVerbStopString{'zzz'}
```

Of course, any alphanumeric character string will do in place of 'zzz'